# MFC C++: TODO <file description> has stopped working

Tags: c++, windows, file, mfc, system

I have wrote a program which tries to write a file in C:\windows\ directory. I have tested the program in several PCs with winXP, win7 (64 & 32 bit).But when i install it in my client's PC it crashed with the message  : TODO ( file description ) has stopped working
Please if anybudy knows any solution then reply me.

Comment: did you make a release build of the program ?

Comment: @John Paul: Yes made release build of the program

Comment: How shall we know a solution if we can't inspect the code? You can't just call your father and say "My car stopped working. What should I do?". Reasons go from battery broken, gasoline gone, oil gone, overheating, broken spark plugs, punctures, steering wheel stolen, car stolen, time bomb inside, trying to drive up a mountain, traffic jam, passenger too weightful, etc. etc. See what I mean?

Comment: @ phresnel: Thank u Phresnel for ur valuable comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite awesome that you gave your client a "TODO:..." product? Please edit the version info to reflect your product name~

As for crash scenario:

- Check if your application really needs Admin rights, if yes, start with "run as admin" and see it it solves the problem.
- View the problem details in either "Stopped working dialog box", or in Windows event viewer. In both, you can see the exception code (like 0xC0000005) and the DLL name. For this you should enable PDB file generation by enabling `/DEBUG` flag in linker setting (this is **not** same as _DEBUG macro in compiler settings!).
- Put some file-logging or message-boxing (temporary) and see till where program goes properly. Yes, you need to make few changes, build and give again to your client (and please no "TODO" as product name - be professional!).

Answer (score 5):

The solution is not to write to the `C:\Windows` folder. You're not working for the Microsoft Windows team.

Comment: @rahhh: That's unfortunate. As Raymond Chen of Micrsoft always says, "We trusted programmers to do the right thing". Only now are they more actively enforcing the old rules.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible causes, among them no write access(perhaps the user running the program does not have write access to C:\Windows folder. Try to manually create a file in that location.) or faulty programming.

In any case, you have a few things to try to figure out the problem. If debug is impossible you should put the sensible parts of the code in [try catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dekhbbc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) blocks (for example the part where you write the file). And if error is caught you can output a message about the part where the error is. You should also include a [logging solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696321/best-logging-framework-for-native-c) and add logs in various places of the code. After you install the updated application, when you get an error, look up in the log file to see where the code stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have UAC turned off, but your client doesn't? Or, would the client's user not have administrative rights? A user process would not be allowed to write to the c:\Windows folder. If that's the case, trying to create a file would throw an exception.

The proper place to create a data file would be:

1. Application Data under the user's folder, if the file is per user.
2. ProgramData (Win7) or Application Data under All Users (XP), if the file is per application (log or so).

Comment: I have tried to run the program on client PC with administrator user but it results the same error.

Comment: @rahhh, just to be sure - did you try to run it with a user who's a member of the administrators group, or did you use "run as administrator" to run the program? If it's a Vista/7/2008 station, you should have used both - use a local admin user, and run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the issue of permissions the first thing that will cause your application to crash like that is the runtimes not being installed on your client's PC. Does your install package install the MSVC runtimes? If not, have you installed the MSVC redistributable runtimes on that PC?

Answer (score 0):

"I have wrote a program which tries to write a file in C:\windows\ directory. "

That's your problem right there. Don't do that.